# Date time format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

i have a string like "14-Nov-2014" , i want to convert this string to this 14.11.2014 format.
after converting i want to add 14 days to above date.
given date is not Datetime format.
Old date="14-Nov-2014"
new date=14.11.2014

is there any way to do in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming,

```
var myString = "14-Nov-2014";
```

---

First parse the string, most likely using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx). Assuming a few things about the [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you have, you could do the following. Note you most likely should specify the proper culture for the third argument:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "dd-MMM-yyyy", null);
```

Then you can [add 14 days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to it easily:

```
var dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(14);
```

To get a new string in a different format just use [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example:

```
var myNewString = dateTime.ToString("d.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: @user1942546 Don't forget to select this as your answer.

Comment: Since you used `null` as a `IFormatProvider`, there is no guaranteed OP's `CurrentCulture` parse the `Nov` part with `MMM` specifier. Would be better to use some english-based culture like `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes this is exactly why I said "Note you most likely should specify the proper culture for the third argument". I have no idea what format the string is in and where it is coming from. If it is from user input, it's very likely it will be in the culture of the eventual user, and not always in English - which is why I left it null.